# What's the Swift 3 equivalent of this C for loop?

Tags: swift, loops

I am trying to do convert this C code:
    int i;

```
for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {

}
```

in Swift 3, but I am not sure how to do it.

I know that if if I want to do it in ascending order if i, I can simply write:

```
for i in 0..<10 {

}
```

But how do I do it in descending order of i?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

```
// reverse a range
for i in (0...9).reversed() {
    // ...
}

// use stride
for i in stride(from: 9, through: 0, by: -1) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in (0 ..< 10).reversed() {

}
```